# Как прочитать файл .xls полученный из интернета?

Tags: python, excel, requests, xlrd

Пытаюсь прочитать файл .xls полученный из интернета с помощью `requests`, чтобы в дальнейшем превратить его в массив или список словарей. Нужны из файла два столбца, без анализа данных.

Пробовал так:

```
import requests as r
import xlrd
data = r.get(‘ https://zniis.ru/router/router-13_05_2020.xls’)
book = xlrd.open_workbook(data)
```

Мне отвечает, что `data` имеет тип `response`, и не читается.

Кто уже делал подобное, как сделать парвильно?

---

Теперь попробовал так, работает:

```
import requests as r
import xlrd

data = r.get('https://zniis.ru/router/router-14_05_2020.xls', verify=False)

with open('router-14_05_2020.xls', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data.content)

book = xlrd.open_workbook('router-14_05_2020.xls')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
```

Но проблема в том, что я все равно, сохраняю файл.
В общем, теперь вопрос такой, как скормить библиотеке `xld` тип `bytes`, чтобы он увидел в нем .xls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функцию [xlrd.open_workbook](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.open_workbook) можно передать параметр `file_contents` ([исходный код](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/a7a22475cbfd76bcc75d5d755c6ded794d53abc7/xlrd/__init__.py#L116)):

> file_contents – A string or an mmap.mmap object or some other
>   behave-alike object. If file_contents is supplied, filename will not
>   be used, except (possibly) in messages.

Думаю, будет так:

```
import requests as r
import xlrd

rs = r.get('https://zniis.ru/router/router-14_05_2020.xls', verify=False)

book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=rs.content)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Откройте для себя модуль [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) - он идеально подходит для обработки, анализа и визуализации табличных данных.

```
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas  #  conda install pandas

df = pd.read_excel("https://zniis.ru/router/router-13_05_2020.xls")
```

---

дальше вы можете работать с прочитанными данными:

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
      Код DEF       От       До  Емкость (всего номеров)     Оператор связи  Идентификатор региона  MNC  \
0         900        0    61999                    62000    "Т2 Мобайл" ООО                     25   20
1         900    62000    62999                     1000    "Т2 Мобайл" ООО                     62   20
2         900    63000    99999                    37000    "Т2 Мобайл" ООО                     25   20
3         900   100000   199999                   100000    "Т2 Мобайл" ООО                     70   20
4         900   200000   299999                   100000    "Т2 Мобайл" ООО                     75   20
...       ...      ...      ...                      ...                ...                    ...  ...
7783      999  9480000  9489999                    10000  "СИМ ТЕЛЕКОМ" ООО                     77   47
7784      999  9490000  9499999                    10000      "МегаФон" ПАО                     14    2
7785      999  9500000  9599999                   100000  "СИМ ТЕЛЕКОМ" ООО                     77   47
7786      999  9600000  9799999                   200000      "Скартел" ООО                     77   11
7787      999  9800000  9999999                   200000      "Скартел" ООО                     77   11

     Маршрутный номер
0               D2520
1               D6220
2               D2520
3               D7020
4               D7520
...               ...
7783            D7747
7784            D1402
7785            D7747
7786            D7711
7787            D7711

[7788 rows x 8 columns]
```